# getChars() using StringBuffer

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am new to Java.
I executed the below program successfully but I don't understand the output.
This is the program.

```
public class StringBufferCharAt {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        System.out.println("Length of sb : " + sb.length());

        int start = 0;
        int end   = 10;

        char arr[] = new char[end - start];
        sb.getChars(start, end, arr, 0);
        System.out.println("After altering : "+ arr.toString());

    }
}
```

After executing this program: I got the following output:

```
Length of sb : 26
After altering : [C@21a722ef
```

**My Questions:**

1. Instead of printing 10 characters in the output, why 11 characters.
2. Instead of printing the original characters "abcdefghij" which are
   inside sb, why did I get some other characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arr.toString()` in your last sentence is giving you a String value of your Object (doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)), here's an array. What you were probably trying to achieve was something like `Arrays.toString(arr)` which will print the content of your array ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29)).

Comment: That JavaDoc link is horribly out of date. How about [something a bit more recent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL ahah you're right, I don't know it's the first link I got on Google for Arrays, changed for yours now thanks :) (Luckily this specific doc doesn't change that much ;))

Answer (score 2):

#### Why is the output 11 characters, and what do those characters mean?

It just so happens that the string representation of the `char[]`, as specified by `Object#toString()`, is 11 characters: the `[C` indicates that it's a `char[]`, the `@` indicates the following 8 hex digits are an address in memory. As the JavaDoc states,

> This method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

[`Class#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) returns `"C["` for a char array, and [the default `hashCode()` implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) (generally) returns the object's address in memory:

> This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.

---

#### How should this be solved?

If you want to print the contents of an array, **use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29):**

```
// Instead of this:
System.out.println("After altering : "+ arr.toString());
// Use this:
System.out.println("After altering : "+ Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have final print statement like this:

```
System.out.println("After altering : "+ new String(arr));
```

OR

```
System.out.println("After altering : "+ java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
For 1st case: abcdefghij
For 2nd case: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
```

**Note:** `arr.toString()` doesn't print the content of array that's why you need to construct a new `` `String object from char array like in my answer above or call ``Arrays.toString(arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java do not have any built in 'human readable' toString() implementations.  What you see is just standard output derived from the memory location of the array.

The easiest way to turn a char[] into something printable is to just build a string out of it.

```
System.out.println("After altering : " + String.valueOf(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `arr.toString()` does not convert a `char[]` to a String using the contents of the `char[]`; it uses the default `Object.toString()` method, which is to print a representation of the object (in this case an array object). What you want is either to convert the characters to a String using `new String(arr)` or else an array representation of the characters using `Arrays.toString(arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

The one part of this question I can answer is #1. You are getting back 11 characters because the start and end variables are indexes. 0 is a valid index so, from 0 - 10 there are 11 different numbers.